# laravel. let user login with not unique email

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have users with unique username and not unique email (because one user can have multiple accounts).

Problem: 
Current login logic: user can login with username or email. But if email is not unique, default laravel auth select first record from database with that email and after that, check if password match (or something like that)

Is it good idea to override (somehow) default laravel login method and select from database record that match username and password hash. like this:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->where('password', Hash::make($password))->first();
```

or it is dumb solution and I should find another one?

Comment: What will you do if they use the same password for two accounts? (A very common scenario, in my experience.)

Comment: @ceejayoz That's a very valid point. I have amended my answer to address this, as this can be accomplished with the exact same code in my answer.

Comment: then user should input username. Users may be angry if i ask to input username every time on login with not unique email. So i'm trying to find the best solution

Comment: Well the user is still (hopefully anyway) the same user. Do you really want one user to require multiple email addresses or usernames? Also, you could have an Account model that forms a belongsTo relationship with a User, this way you have multiple Account on one User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here: `where('password', Hash::make($password))`. The hash will be different every time with the same password. It's not MD5 and as such, you cannot compare it against the string in the database.

So, you need to loop through and hash check to find the correct, if any, one like so...

```php
$users = User::where('email', $email)->get();
$authenticateable = false;

foreach($users as $user) {
    if(Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
        $authenticateable = $user;
        break;
    }
}

if($authenitcateable) {
    // Login
} else {
    // Handle bad login attempt
}
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing) on hashing

**Edit**

As @ceejayoz accurately stated in the comments, this does leave the OP open to duplicate passwords for the same email. The solution for that is simple enough. During registration, you need to do the exact same loop through users and if a user is found with the same email and matching password, return a response that rejects this account. As such, this loop should be placed within a trait or somewhere that can be accessed from both login and registration methods.